# Python "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask'"

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am a beginner with the python programming.
I have python 3 installed in my local system.
I coding along as part of a tutorial video and as part of the tutorial, i have created a virtual environment and created an app.py file with the below content.

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return "Hello, World!"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

I have installed all the dependencies like flask and pytest in the virtual environment as per the tutorial using gitbash.But when i run the command python3 app.py in gitbash i get the below error message

```
 File "C:\path\Python\python-github-actions-example\src\app.py", line 1, in <module>
    from flask import Flask
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask'
(myvenv)
```

I checked the python version and it is python 3.9.7

If i run python app.py i get the output.
Why is it not running even though correct version is installed

Any idea why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to delete the `venv` or make a new one.

1. Then create a new `venv` like this:
   `virtualenv flask`
2. Go to the flask directory
   : `cd flask`
3. Activate it: `scripts\activate`

   - You should see (*flask*) on the left of the command line.
4. Install flask again: `pip install flask`
5. Run your file again.

Comment: As is evident from OP's post, he uses Windows, so step (3) should read `scripts\activate`. Personally I merge steps 2 and 3 and do `source flask/bin/activate` on Linux or `flask\scripts\activate` on Windows.

Comment: @Luke Fixed it, thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the comments.
I ran the below script to set up the `venv`
`python3 - m venv myvenv` and then activated by running `scripts\activate`
And then installed flask and other dependencies.
I have done the same thing as the above answer, only difference is the `venev` name , i have is different.

Answer (score 1):

**Some times you** need to change/select de versión/env if you after installed. like it if work for you.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

After you do what @kmogi says in their [post above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69623603/13855522), start the app with `python` not `python3`.